# JsonParseException while trying to map Json

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am trying to map Json to POJO but I am getting this exception:

This is my code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                try {
                    InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("user.json");

                    List<MessageCenterResponse> mcr = (List<MessageCenterResponse>) mapper.readValue(content, MessageCenterResponse.class);
                    System.out.println(mcr);
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();   
                }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@41e86930; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Is it something related to type issue?

Comment: What do you think `is.toString();` does and why do you think so?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to take that off, but when I do with inputstream itself I am getting this: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of MessageCenterResponse out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@41e83dc8; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: Why did you now get rid of the type token?

Comment: even after adding type token I am still getting can not deserialize instance of MessageCenterResponse out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: Show us how you are using it. It should be a `TypeReference<List<MessageCenterResponse>>`.

Comment: This is how I a doing :                         List<MessageCenterResponse> mcr = (List<MessageCenterResponse>) mapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<List<MessageCenterResponse>>() {});

Comment: Then your JSON is not in the format you expected. Post a sample of your JSON. Post your `MessageCenterResponse` class. Edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

The `InputStream` class inherits its `toString()` method from `Object` where it is implemented (Oracle JDK 7) as

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

In other words, it doesn't read the stream and return the content as a `String`.

You need to do that yourself with [any number of techniques for reading from an `InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html). Or pass the `InputStream` directly to the `ObjectMapper` method.

```
List<MessageCenterResponse> mcr = mapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<List<MessageCenterResponse>>() {});
```